# Replacing Do ... While Loops

Tags: php, curl, loops

I have the following piece of code taken from the PHP manual on the curl_multi_* entries:

```
$active = null;

do {
    $process = curl_multi_exec($curl, $active);
} while ($process === CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while (($active >= 1) && ($process === CURLM_OK))
{
    if (curl_multi_select($curl, 3) != -1)
    {
        do {
            $process = curl_multi_exec($curl, $active);
        } while ($process === CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
}
```

Now the thing is I really don't like writing do...while loops and I was wondering what would is the best and shorter way to accomplish the same but without using this kind of loops.

So far I've come up with a slightly longer version but I'm not sure if it does exactly the same or if it performs the same way as the original one:

```
while (true)
{
    $active = 1;
    $process = curl_multi_exec($curl, $active);

    if ($process === CURLM_OK)
    {
        while (($active >= 1) && (curl_multi_select($curl, 3) != -1))
        {
            $process = CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM;

            while ($process === CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM)
            {
                $process = curl_multi_exec($curl, $active);
            }
        }

        break;
    }

    else if ($process === CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM)
    {
        continue;
    }

    break;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Um... what's wrong with do...while() loops? Specifically, the first version is clear and you're replacing it with a while(true) loop? To what end?

Comment: While I find do_while loops archaic, I agree with cletus - there isn't any benefit to change to a WHILE loop.  I can see if you use counter manipulation to change from WHILE to FOR, but that's it...

Comment: Who's afraid of the do while's? ;)

Comment: The code used should be based on what you need to do the job, not on what you "like to write".

Comment: @GZipp: Really? I had no idea... There is something called coding style, it helps sometimes to make some trade-offs in the name of consistency. Those kind of comments while valid provide absolutely no value whatsoever.

Comment: Well, now I know the value of validity. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Do..While` loops are near exact to `While` loops, except that they ensure the code within the `Do..While` loop executes *at least* once.  So the simple way to convert `Do..While` loops is to pull out the code from the `Do..While` so that it executes once and convert to `While`.

```
do {
    action();
} while(...)
```

is equivalent to:

```
action();
while(...) {
   action();
}
```

So applied to your code the change would look like:

```
$active = null;

$process = curl_multi_exec($curl, $active);
while ($process === CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM) {
    $process = curl_multi_exec($curl, $active);
}

while (($active >= 1) && ($process === CURLM_OK))
{
    if (curl_multi_select($curl, 3) != -1)
    {
       $process = curl_multi_exec($curl, $active);
       while ($process === CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM) {
           $process = curl_multi_exec($curl, $active);
       };
    }
}
```

With that said, there's nothing wrong with `Do..While` loops and you should use them if you need to.

Answer (score 8):

I don't see a problem with do while loops.  They should be used when the code within the loops contains something that should be executed at least 1 time and more times if a condition is met.

IMO, I think your first set of code is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Will this do?

```
$active = null;

$process = curl_multi_exec($curl, $active);
while ($process === CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM) {
    $process = curl_multi_exec($curl, $active);
};

$process = curl_multi_exec($curl, $active);
while (($active >= 1) && ($process === CURLM_OK)) {
    if (curl_multi_select($curl, 3) != -1) {
        while ($process === CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM) {
            $process = curl_multi_exec($curl, $active);
        } 
    }
}
```