# How can I re-code my php script to run as quickly as possible?

Tags: php, performance

I'm running a script which will check the availability (10 times) of a domain name and output the domain, if available and a timestamp (with milliseconds).

Can you find anything which is slowing down the script even marignally?
If you could please adjust and re-post or advise what can be done better, it would be very much appreciated! Thank you.

```
<?php

    date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Brisbane');
    $loops = 0; 

    function udate($format, $utimestamp = null) {
      if (is_null($utimestamp))
        $utimestamp = microtime(true);

      $timestamp = floor($utimestamp);
      $milliseconds = round(($utimestamp - $timestamp) * 1000000);

      return date(preg_replace('`(?<!\\\\)u`', $milliseconds, $format), $timestamp);
    }

    function GetCurlPage ($pageSpec)
    {
      $ch = curl_init($pageSpec);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
      $tmp = curl_exec ($ch);
      curl_close ($ch);
      $tmp = preg_replace('/(?s)<meta http-equiv="Expires"[^>]*>/i', '', $tmp);
      $tmp = explode('<br>', $tmp);
      foreach ($tmp AS $line) {
        //echo '<pre>';
        //print_r($line);
        //echo '</pre>';
      }
      // Do something with each line.
      echo $tmp[0];
      echo "<br>";
      echo $tmp[1];
      //echo $tmp[2];
      echo "<br>";
      echo udate('H:i:s:u');
      echo "<br><br>";

      return $tmp;

    }

    while ($loops <= 10)    
    {
$suffixes=urlencode("com.au");
$domain = "sampledomain";
$fuzzysearch = "0";
$returnUrl="http://mydomain.com.au/test.php";
$url = "https://apidomain.com.au/check.php?domain=" .
$domain . "&suffixes=" . $suffixes . "&fuzzysearch=" . $fuzzysearch;
$output = GetCurlPage("$url");

    ++$loops;
    }           
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The slowness because you need to make 10 curl to external site

Two suggestions

- update your test.php/check.php to allow multiple domain name check at one curl call (instead of checking one-by-one, pass an array)
- use [curl_multi_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) to allow parallel curl 10 different URLs at the same time

I would prefer *suggestion 1*

Comment: @ajreal it seems like the best option! that with other users suggestions should do the trick :) thanks. Now how can I set up an array with the curl call for multiple domains? Sorry, first time user of curl

Comment: @iCeR - such as `https://apidomain.com.au/check.php?domain1=abc.com&domain2=def.com&domain3=ghi...` **OR** `https://apidomain.com.au/check.php?domain[]=abc.com&domain[]=def.com&domain[]=ghi...`

Comment: No luck coding it up :( sorry. Possible to assist editing my code as per above?

Comment: @iCeR - You can build the query using [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) . Do you have access to check.php?

Comment: oh... try method 2 instead ... if you not able to update check.php, example of how to use [curl_multi-exec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669541/replacing-do-while-loops)

Answer (score 1):

- Don't put the code from `$suffixes=urlencode("com.au");` until `$domain . "&suffixes=" . $suffixes . "&fuzzysearch=" . $fuzzysearch;` in the loop
- Remove the empty `foreach ($tmp AS $line) {` loop
- Don't do the regex stuff in udate and don't use a parameter there, instead let udate do it using string concatenation

Answer (score 0):

Change `if (is_null($utimestamp))` by `if ($utimestamp === null)` to prevent PHP from having to call the function `is_null()`.